# Error MSB3644 during publish solution in Visual studio for Mac

Tags: mono, .net-standard, visual-studio-mac, multiplatform, visual-studio-publish

I use Visual Studio for Mac 8.5.4 (the latest at this moment).

My solution contains asp.net core app with target framework 3.0 **with a few Portal Library projects** with some logic.
[image]

I'm able to build and run the application successfully, but not publish. The errors related to the Portal Library projects.

[image]

Errors if the Portal Library projects have target framework as **.NET Portable**:
[image]

> dotnet publish
>   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

Errors if the Portal Library projects have target framework as **.NET Standart Platform**:
[image]

> dotnet publish
>   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETPortable,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

I'm not sure what I have to install? I downloaded the latest SDK from the https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks and installed it already.

Comment: dotnet publish does not support PCL projects. You should use a .NET Standard (SDK style) project instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Now it's clearer that I should investigate in the .NET Standard direction. As you can see from my post, in this case, VS error asking about Developer Pack, I installed the latest SDK, what else could be missing? P.S. I did a workaround, instead of referencing the projects, I was able to reference the dll's itself and publish the solution, but I don't like such approach.

Comment: The developer packs are mainly specific to Windows (at least for .NET Framework). On the Mac you have Mono and the .NET Core SDKs.